# SetInterval only runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, setinterval

This is my JavaScript code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function mytest() {

        var jqxhr = $.get("Home/GetMonitorData", function (data) {
        $("#cpu").text(data.cpu);
        $("#dspace").text(data.dspace);
        $("#cspace").text(data.cspace);
        $("#pf").text(data.pf);
        $("#totphysical").text(data.totphysical);
        $("#freephysical").text(data.freephysical);
        $("#tcp").text(data.tcp);
        $("#req").text(data.req);


    }, "json");

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(mytest, 3000);
}); 



</script>
```

The issue is, setInterval only runs once. My program is supposed to get some WMI Information from an action method, print in on screen, and refresh these values every 3 seconds. But after one refresh, it stops. Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: I find when setInterval fails to continually run, it's due to a javascript error in the timer function (at least, that's what FireFox does).  Have you checked the javascript error log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `Request.Expires = 0` when calling ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ajax requests stack because there is no time and then break the chain?

Try increasing the interval size for debugging purposes and see if the situation has changed.